# kendoGrid 2013.1.319 CRUD general issue using OData through ASP.NET MVC 4 web api controller

Tags: kendo-ui

Since I've tryed to write on kendoui forum but the answer I've got was "buy a license" for report a bug, I'm asking if someone has faced the same problem using kendoGrid 2013.1.319. Since I'm using it in a "sundays test application" there's no hurry at all!

**My original message was on kendo forum was:**

Hi there,

I've been updated kendo grid with the latest version and all of a sudden my application is facing problems on data operations. The problem seems to be located client side, because I'm correctly receiving requests for GET, PUT, POST and DELETE verbs but the grid does not update its status.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 OData implementation through an API service.

For example: if I delete 2 rows and press save, the DELETE calls are made, the client grid hides the rows but if I press save again, the delete is called on and on.

The same problem is on update / create, the cell remains with the red corner and, after saving, again the data are still submitted as it was the first time.

I've noticed that when I receiving the callback on dataSource:

```
requestEnd: function (e) {
            if (e.type === "update" || e.type === "create") {
                // Refresh data after changes
                this.read();
            }
        }
```

e.type is always undefined when inserting or updating records.

This is my dataSource configuration:

```
dataSource: {
            type: 'odata', // <-- Include OData style params on query string
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: $("#contactsGrid").attr("data-api-crud"),
                    dataType: "json", // <-- The default is "jsonp".
                    type: "GET"
                },
                update: {
                    url: $("#contactsGrid").attr("data-api-crud"),
                    dataType: "json", // <-- The default is "jsonp".
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: $("#contactsGrid").attr("data-api-crud"),
                    dataType: "json", // <-- The default is "jsonp".
                    type: "PUT"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: function (data) {
                        return $("#contactsGrid").attr("data-api-crud") + "/" + data.Id;
                    },
                    dataType: "json", // <-- The default is "jsonp".
                    type: "DELETE"
                },
                parameterMap: kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap
            },
            schema: {
                // The array of repeating data elements (items)
                data: "Results",
                // The total count of records in the whole dataset. used for paging.
                total: "Count",
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Dealer: { type: "string", editable: true },
                        Address: { type: "string", editable: true }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 50,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            requestEnd: function (e) {
                if (e.type === "update" || e.type === "create") {
                    // Refresh data after changes
                    this.read();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: For clarification, are you saying that it used to work on an older version of Kendo, but is now not working in 2013.1, or have you never had this working?

Comment: It sounds like this: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string Try not returning empty response.

Comment: This code use to work properly within the last major release. Since it's calling a web api for updating data, i'm returning an HttpResponseMessage with StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK when success but not setting the response Content. The read is done by an IQueryable exposed directly from the controller (that worked well, pagination and stuff).

Answer (score 4):

the Kendo UI team have just published a [blogpost](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-03-26/introducing-jaydata-and-kendo-ui.aspx) how to use the library with JayData to simplify the configuration of datasources. Hopefully it will help you.